# cambiar idioma español-ingles utilizando SQLite en c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Estaba intentando cambiar el idioma de mi formulario utilizando la base de datos `SQLite` en `C#` con `Visual Studio 2017` (libreria System.Data.SQLite.dll). Para ello tengo una clase que se encarga de traducir haciendo una consulta.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lib_SopCnf.src.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Manager de traducciones a partir de una BBDD SQLite
    /// </summary>
    public class TranslationsManager
    {
        #region Atributos privados

    /// <summary>
    /// Objeto de conexión con la BD.
    /// </summary>
    SQLiteConnection _dbConnection;

    #endregion Atributos privados

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor por defecto, inicializa la conexión y crea la BD si no existe
    /// </summary>
    public TranslationsManager()
    {
        try
        {
            // Si no existe el archivo de la base de datos, creamos un nuevo fichero
            _dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=TranslationsSopCnfAppCE214DB.sqlite;Version=3;");
            _dbConnection.Open();

            // Si la tabla de idiomas disponibles no existe, se crea
            string lsSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IDIOMAS_DISPONIBLES (codigo_idioma varchar(5) PRIMARY KEY, nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL)";
            SQLiteCommand loCommand = new SQLiteCommand(lsSql, _dbConnection);
            loCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Si la tabla de traducciones disponibles no existe, se crea
            lsSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRADUCCIONES_DISPONIBLES (codigo_idioma varchar(5), grupo_traduccion varchar(40), clave_traduccion varchar(60), traduccion varchar(80) )";
            loCommand = new SQLiteCommand(lsSql, _dbConnection);
            loCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Comprobamos si existe al menos un idioma en el sistema
            if (GetIdiomasDisponibles().Count == 0)
            {
                // Insertamos un idioma por defecto
                lsSql = "INSERT INTO IDIOMAS_DISPONIBLES VALUES ('es-es', 'Español (España)')";
                loCommand = new SQLiteCommand(lsSql, _dbConnection);
                loCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Funciones públicas

    /// <summary>
    /// Devuelve una lista de pares [Cod. Idioma - Nombre] que acepta el sistema
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<string[]> GetIdiomasDisponibles()
    {
        List<string[]> lloReturn = new List<string[]>();

        string lsSql = "SELECT * FROM IDIOMAS_DISPONIBLES";
        SQLiteCommand loSqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(lsSql, _dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader loReader = loSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (loReader.Read())
        {
            string[] loPair = new string[2];
            loPair[0] = loReader["codigo_idioma"].ToString();
            loPair[1] = loReader["nombre"].ToString();

            lloReturn.Add(loPair);
        }
        loReader.Close();

        return lloReturn;
    }

    #endregion Funciones públicas


    /// <summary>
    /// Traduce una cadena de caracteres
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="psIdioma">Código de idioma al que queremos traducir</param>
    /// <param name="psGrupoTraducciones">Grupo de traducciones en el que buscar los literales (Clases)</param>
    /// <param name="psClaveTraduccion">Literal con el que indexamos la búsqueda</param>
    /// <param name="psTraduccion">Cadena traducida</param>
    /// <returns>Número de registros devueltos</returns>
    public int Translate(string psIdioma, string psGrupoTraducciones, string psClaveTraduccion, out string psTraduccion)
    {
        int liReturn = 0;

        psTraduccion = string.Empty;

        string lsSql = "SELECT traduccion FROM TRADUCCIONES_DISPONIBLES WHERE codigo_idioma=\"" + psIdioma +
                        "\" AND grupo_traduccion = \"" + psGrupoTraducciones +
                        "\" AND clave_traduccion = \"" + psClaveTraduccion + "\"";
        SQLiteCommand loSqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(lsSql, _dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader loReader = loSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (loReader.Read())
        {
            psTraduccion = loReader["traduccion"].ToString();

            liReturn++;
        }
        loReader.Close();

        return liReturn;
    }
}
```

}

En el programa principal del formulario hago lo siguiente:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Método para cambiar los textos del formulario según las traducciones cargadas desde la BBDD para el idioma especificado
        /// </summary>
        public void TraducirForm()
        {
            string lsTranslation;

        // ToolStrip
        foreach (ToolStripItem loStripItem in toolStripGeneral.Items)
        {
            if (loStripItem is ToolStripMenuItem)
            {
                if (_oTM.Translate(_sCurrentLanguage, this.GetType().ToString(), ((ToolStripMenuItem)loStripItem).Name, out lsTranslation) > 0)
                    ((ToolStripMenuItem)loStripItem).Text = lsTranslation;
            }
            else if (loStripItem is ToolStripDropDownButton)
            {
                if (_oTM.Translate(_sCurrentLanguage, this.GetType().ToString(), ((ToolStripDropDownButton)loStripItem).Text, out lsTranslation) > 0)
                    ((ToolStripDropDownButton)loStripItem).Text = lsTranslation;

                foreach (ToolStripItem loStripItem2 in ((ToolStripDropDownButton)loStripItem).DropDownItems)
                {
                    if (loStripItem2 is ToolStripMenuItem)
                    {
                        if (_oTM.Translate(_sCurrentLanguage, this.GetType().ToString(), ((ToolStripMenuItem)loStripItem2).Name, out lsTranslation) > 0)
                            ((ToolStripMenuItem)loStripItem2).Text = lsTranslation;

                        foreach (ToolStripItem loStripItem3 in ((ToolStripMenuItem)loStripItem2).DropDownItems)
                        {
                            if (loStripItem3 is ToolStripMenuItem)
                            {
                                if (_oTM.Translate(_sCurrentLanguage, this.GetType().ToString(), ((ToolStripMenuItem)loStripItem3).Name, out lsTranslation) > 0)
                                    ((ToolStripMenuItem)loStripItem3).Text = lsTranslation;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Pero la traducción me devuelve un null.
Para obtener la traducción de la palabra, ¿debo añadir primero el idioma inglés en la SQLite? ¿Alguien sabe por qué no obtengo la traducción?
Si no se entiende algo digánmelo.
Gracias

Comment: Obviamente tienes que tener las traducciones en la base de datos antes de intentar obtenerla, sino siempre te devolvera null, porque básicamente no las encuentra. Lo mismo con el idioma

Comment: y como puedo añadir este paquete de palabras en inglés sin tener que introducirlo una a una?

Comment: No conozco ninguna herramienta que te dé un paquete de traducciones de idiomas, siempre que he hecho alguna aplicación con traduccioones lo he tenido que traducir yo, así que en esto no puedo ayudarte.

Comment: De acuerdo entonces lo que haces es introducir en la base de datos una tabla donde esta cada palabra con su traduccion?

Comment: Creo que vas un poco perdido. No tiene sentido que traduzcas todas y cada una de las palabras del diccionario. Lo que debes hacer es traducir **cada una de las cadenas** que se muestran en tu aplicación. Te recomiendo que leas [esto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/communitydocs/net-dev/csharp/international-apps) para hacerte una idea.

Comment: De acuerdo gracias

Comment: Pero esto es para cuando tienes pocos controles y los añades uno a uno no? Yo tengo mas de 100 controles y controles creados por mi y añadidos como dll. No hay una manera de no tener que estar añadiendo los controles en el archivo de recursos uno a uno? @Pikoh

Comment: No,no hay manera (que yo sepa).La forma de funcionar en general es la del enlace que te he puesto.De todas maneras, 100 cadenas para traducir no son demasiadas...

Comment: Por cierto, no hay que añadir los controles a los archivos de recursos, sino las cadenas. Si dos controles comparte un mismo texto, no hay que añadirlo dos veces,solo una

Comment: De acuerdo gracias @Pikoh

Comment: @Xim123 Si te fijas muchas aplicaciones que instalas llevan paquetes de idiomas, esos paquetes son clases donde hay las traducciones de los textos de los controles. No hay otro método (que yo sepa) que el de traducirlo tu mismo

Comment: De acuerdo gracias @Marc